# Setup apache and SVN

Tags: apache-2.2, svn

Well I have an issue when I want to run SVN, **I already explorer all the related question but I couldn't get what is wrong in my case**. So that's why I decided to post my question in here, kindly help me to double check all the steps.

I am using Apache version 2.0 and my SVN version is 1.4.

I am receiving :"Forbidden You don't have permission to access /svn/ on this server." when 
I enter

```
 http://localhost/svn/
```

in my computer.

> Forbidden You don't have permission to access /svn/ on this server.
>
> ---
>
> Apache/2.0.64 (Win32) SVN/1.4.0 DAV/2 Server at localhost Port 80

I already setup my apache and SVN server based on [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15671/How-to-set-up-Subversion-with-Apache-in-Windows-qu?fid=343349&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&prof=False&sort=Position&view=Quick&spc=Relaxed&fr=26#xx0xx) but I dont know what is wrong with my setup that I am receiving permission deny error message. I am wondering help me and double check my work to identify the root cause of problem.

my httpd.conf:

```
<Location /svn/>
    DAV svn
    SVNParentPath c:/svnroot/ 
    SVNListParentPath on
    AuthzSVNAccessFile bin/apachesvnauth 

    AuthType Basic 
    AuthName "Subversion repository" 
    AuthUserFile bin/apachesvnpasswd 

    Require valid-user                                 </Location>
```

my authentication file.

```
[/]
* = r 

[test1:/] 
user1 = rw 
user2 

[test2:/] 
user1 = r 
user2 = rw
```

If you need any more information keep me posted so I can share with you.
I am using windows xp. one more thing I already assign all the read and write privilege for SVN and repository folder to my own user as well.

my apache log is as below:

```
> [Wed Apr 10 15:49:34 2013] [notice] Server built: Oct 18 2010 01:36:23
> [Wed Apr 10 15:49:34 2013] [notice] Parent: Created child process 1656
> [Wed Apr 10 15:49:35 2013] [notice] Child 1656: Child process is
> running [Wed Apr 10 15:49:35 2013] [notice] Child 1656: Acquired the
> start mutex. [Wed Apr 10 15:49:35 2013] [notice] Child 1656: Starting
> 250 worker threads. [Wed Apr 10 15:49:48 2013] [error] [client
> 10.8.8.139] Access denied: 'user1' GET svn:/
```

Comment: "Apache version 2.0 and my SVN version is 1.4"? Why SVN 1.4? It's too outdated.

Comment: which version you recommend that apache and SVN working properly in both?

Comment: Decide about Apache HTTP Server version yourself, but SVN should not be 1.4. 1.4 is too outdated. The latest version is 1.7.9: http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/

Answer (score 1):

Within your `<Location /svn/>` block, add `Order allow,deny` and `Allow from all`.

Comment: Do u mean like below?
<Location /svn/>
    DAV svn
    SVNParentPath c:/svnroot/ 
    SVNListParentPath on
    AuthzSVNAccessFile bin/apachesvnauth 

    AuthType Basic 
    AuthName "Subversion repository" 
    AuthUserFile bin/apachesvnpasswd 

    Require valid-user        

    Order allow,deny 
    Allow from all                        
</Location>

If your answer is yes, it still isnot working

Comment: I tried below aswell, still same problem:
<Directory "C:/SVN">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory "C:/svnroot">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

Comment: @rima Please provide the output from the Apache error log when one of those requests is made.

Comment: check my edit. in last part I added my log

Comment: @rima Looks like the block is occurring from the svn access file - does it work when you disable it, and/or when you directly access `http://localhost/svn/test1` instead of `http://localhost/svn/`?

Answer (score 1):

1. If your server is Windows-host (as I see from `SVNParentPath` string), write **full path** (not relative) to AuthzSVNAccessFile|AuthUserFile
2. You can test anonymous access to repository by adding (temporary) `Satisfy any` into Location container
3. **If** you want to have explicit access-rules in config (while missing means `Allow from all` AFAICR), and string to Location container also, not Directory
4. Test configuration by accessing

   - **Repository**, not repositories root
   - by **SVN-client**, not browser (you'll see all possible trobles in one shot)

5.Fix user2 in test1 repo, use correct format of line

Comment: I tried but non of above solution helped. I didnt understand the step 4 would you explain more? if you mean I try to connect localhost/svn/ from GUI, I tried but it couldnt fetch any xml!

Comment: @rima - point 4 is "Use `svn ls http:localhost/test2/ (when repo in test2 exist) - it produce more readable error, that browser`"